# Ajax users load more / filters issue, no more users to load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with AJAX "Load More" functionality in WordPress when attempting to load additional users after applying a filter. Here are the details:

1. The initial set of users loads correctly and also using AJAX "Load
   More" functionality, works well
2. After applying a filter and loading the correct set of users, they
   are no more users to show even if they are.
3. Interestingly, changing the "number per page" parameter makes the
   missing users appear.

i use the load more for posts and separately for users wp_users_query, posts have 0 issues, the issue is with the users load more..

```
/*
* Load More for Users
*/
function loadMoreUsers(role, currentPage, selectedFilters, currentTab) {
var action = 'loadmore_users_button';
var nonce = loadmore_users_params.loadmore_nonce;
$.ajax({
url: loadmore_users_params.ajaxurl,
data: {
'action': action,
'security': nonce,
'query': loadmore_params.posts,
'role': role,
'page': currentPage,
'selectedFilters': selectedFilters
},
type: 'POST',
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
currentTab.find('.loadmore_users').text('loading...');
},
success: function (response) {
if (response.success) {
currentTab.find('#users_wrap').append(response.data.content);
currentPage++;
if (currentPage >= response.data.max_page) {
currentTab.find('.loadmore_users').text('All users loaded').prop('disabled', true);
// currentTab.find('.loadmore_users').hide();
}
} else {
currentTab.find('.loadmore_users').hide();
}
}
});
}

$('.loadmore_users').click(function () {
var currentPage = 0;
var role = $(this).data('role');
var parentTab = $(this).closest('.roles').attr('id');
var currentTab = $('#' + role);
loadMoreUsers(role, currentPage, selectedFilters, currentTab);
return false;
});
```

```
function loadmore_users_ajax_handler()
{
check_ajax_referer('loadmore_users_nonce', 'security');
$query_params = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['query']), true);
$role = isset($_POST['role']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['role']) : '';
$pagename = isset($query_params['pagename']) ? sanitize_text_field($query_params['pagename']) : '';
$selectedFilters = isset($_POST['selectedFilters']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['selectedFilters']) : '';
$selected_region = isset($_POST['selectedFilters']['postcode']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['selectedFilters']['postcode']) : '';
$number_per_page = 2;
if (isset($_POST['selectedFilters']) && !empty(array_filter($_POST['selectedFilters']))) {

$page_number = 1;
$offset = 0;
} else {
$page_number = absint($_POST['page']) + 1;
$offset = ($page_number - 1) * $number_per_page;
}
$users_args = array(
'role' => 'um_' . $role,
'meta_key' => 'account_status',
'meta_value' => 'approved',
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'AND',
),
'number' => $number_per_page,
'paged' => $page_number,
// 'offset' => ($page_number - 1) * $number_per_page,
);
if (!empty($selected_region)) {
$users_args['meta_query'][] = array(
'key' => 'plz_feld',
'value' => '^' . preg_quote($selected_region, '^'),
'compare' => 'REGEXP',
);
}
if ($pagename === 'national') {
$users_args['meta_query'][] = array(
'relation' => 'OR',
array(
'key' => 'country',
'value' => array('Deutschland', 'DE'),
'compare' => 'IN',
),
);
} else {
$users_args['meta_query'][] = array(
'relation' => 'AND',
array(
'key' => 'country',
'value' => array('Deutschland', 'DE'),
'compare' => 'NOT IN',
),
);
}
perform_query($users_args, $number_per_page, $page_number, $pagename, $selectedFilters, 'users');
}
```

and the perform query part for users..

```
$users_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
$users = $users_query->get_results();
ob_start();
$max_page = intval($users_query->total_users / $number_per_page);
// error_log('Max Page: ' . $max_page);
// error_log('total users: ' . $users_query->total_users);
if ($users) {
foreach ($users as $user) {
um_fetch_user($user->ID);
get_template_part('parts/single-user', 'event');
}
} else {
wp_send_json_error('No more users');
}
$response = ob_get_clean();
wp_send_json_success(array(
'content' => $response,
'max_page' => $max_page,
));
```

would be happy if someone can help

Comment: Sounds like you are "on" a page number already with your user "load more" functionality, that is greater than the number of pages there actually are, after the filter criteria have been applied ...? _"would be happy if someone can help"_ - could you make that code readable first of all, by using some proper indentation? Might increase your chances, that someone will actually look at it in detail.